# How to view Latex compiler error messages using Lyx?

Tags: errors, lyx

I do not seem to find how to view the latex error messages when I use "View DVI" or "Export to PDF", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Document menu has an item "LaTeX Log", which shows the last log file for the current file if it exists, otherwise is greyed out.

Comment: Thanks. In the current case, lyx was not producing any "Latex Log" at all (grayed) even though there was an error in the document.